# Mocking JestClient in SpringBoot

Tags: mockito, elasticsearch-5, spring-boot-test

Springboot application is not autowiring all the instances so I manually wire all of them. Now `JestClient` mock is not getting set I only see the live object. Next actually I want to test if "aMethod is having jestclient.execute() then return jestResult"

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = IngestionApplicationTests.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.package.accounts" })
public class IngestionApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private IngestionServiceImpl vaService;

    @Autowired
    private IngestionQueryUtil queryUtil;

    @Mock
    private JestClient client;

    private JestResult result;

...
    @Before
    public void setUp() {

    client = mock(JestClient.class);
    String resultString="<jsonString>";
    result.setJsonString(resultString);
    result.setJsonObject(new JsonParser().parse(resultString).getAsJsonObject());
    result.setSucceeded(true);

    try {
            when(client.execute(anyObject())).thenReturn(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
```

I see that Spring-Boot is creating a new context of its own and not running in test context.